# Why does Firefox show multiple lines of code in HTML comments as a single line?

Tags: firefox, web-development

When I inspect a website, Firefox compacts HTML code into one line

[image: firefox]

I can see multiple lines only if I edit the code
[image: firefox-2]

Here is how Chrome shows the same code. And I think it is more appropriate way. Is there some option in Firefox to make it act like Chrome?

[image]

In Drupal it is necessary for themming and because of this I can not use Firefox for development :(